# Convert HTACCESS to WEB.CONFIG IIS7

Tags: php, iis-7

I have this .htaccess file. When importing it to IIS via URL Rewrite module it is giving errors. Can someone please help convert it to webconfig.

Thanks in advance

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad. We tend to discourage "convert this code for me" questions, as they are essentially requests for free work. Can you show what errors you are getting, and what you have tried thus far to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third condition "is symbolic link" is not supported in IIS rewrite module. If there's no symbolic link implemented, the following rule will be the equivalent:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?action={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mauritius, however symbolic links are used within the application. Is there a way to make this work on IIS or I have to go for Linux /Apache hosting ?

Comment: Hello, as far as I know, "is symbolic link" is not supported. If you have control over the server, you can install php over windows, else opt for Linux/Apache hosting where it is very much cheaper as well.

Comment: Thanks alot. I'll see what I can do.